# Sockets vs websockets, what is the difference, advantages?

Tags: sockets, websocket

I am having a hard time figuring the motivation behind websockets. From what I've read around the web, regular sockets are still faster and more efficient, so in short, why would I want to use websockets, when and where?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sockets are a lower level. They can work with any type of netwroking. Websockets are at a higher level. They power web servers, and drive web apps. A websocket can be made via plain sockets. It is jsut a lower/higher level thing. Websockets are more of a convience thing. They require you to write less code

Comment: So if I know socket programming, I do not need to bother with websockets? It is just an abstraction then?

Comment: As my edit said, the just require you to write less code, and yes if you know what you r doing you can use plain sockets.

Comment: That's what I needed to know, tanks a lot :)

Comment: also depends on the client/server in use, if you are working with a browser client then websocket is a viable technology that lets you not have to deal with that on the client side...if you are in control of both client and server side, tis up to you

Comment: Yes, I understand how websockets will be more applicable in web applications, whereas regular sockets, at least in my experience, are used in native code - something quite awkward to do in a browser application.

Comment: A lot of the time I see sockest to construct simple webservers

Answer (score 1):

And regarding why to bother with websockets:
It's mainly because browsers only support the Websocket API in their Javascript APIs and do no provide direct TCP socket support.
This was done to prevent (possibly malicious) Javascript apps to create any kind of TCP connections which could provide them confidential information and forward it to the internet.
With Websockets Webapps can only connect to websocket servers. The websocket protocol uses an obfuscation mechanism that prevents that webapps can send any kind of raw TCP data.

Comment: Actually, that is not nessecarily true HTTP is built off of TCP, so a web server can easily be implemented with sockets, and it's output be seen in a browser.

Comment: The OP wanted a comparison between websockets and raw TCP sockets and not to HTTP. I know that a browsers and JS can  use both HTTP and WS, but not plain tcp. And that was correctly laid down in my answer.